# How to properly add pagination to a PHP file

Tags: php, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination to my query. For this example, I'm just using a previous and next link. When I look at the page in the browser I get a Notice:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant url - assumed 'url' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\pagination-test.php on line 25.
```

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'myroot', 'corporate');
$pagesize = 4;

$recordstart = (isset($_GET['recordstart'])) ? $recordstart : 0;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id AS `ID`, sku AS `SKU`, price AS `PRICE` FROM products ORDER BY id LIMIT ?, ?");

$stmt->bind_param("ii", $recordstart, $pagesize);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(id) AS count FROM products");
list($totalrows) = $result->fetch_row();

// Create the 'previous' link
if ($recordstart > 0) {
    $prev = $recordstart - $pagesize;
    $url = isset($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?recordstart=$prev";
    printf("<a href='%s'>Previous</a>", url);
}

// Create the 'next' link
if ($totalrows > ($recordstart + $pagesize)){
    $next = $recordstart + $pagesize;
    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?recordstart=$next";
    printf("<a href='%s'>Next Page</a>", url);
}
```

Can anyone please help me solve this?

Thanks!

PS: Also, what is the ii used for in the bind_param statement? Shouldn't it just be $recordstart and $pagesize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code, and if you don't understand I will provide you information.

```
<?php 

/*  Please disable this before uploading to the remote server, 
    After you finished, then enable this so your application gain one more level of security...
    http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
*/
error_reporting(0);

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>AwatITWork</title>
</head>

<body>
<?Php
require "config.php";           // All database details will be included here 

$page_name="index2.php"; //  If you use this code with a different page ( or file ) name then change this 
$start=$_GET['start'];
if(strlen($start) > 0 and !is_numeric($start)){
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}


// This is the core of pagination and its simple :)
$eu = ($start - 0); 
$limit = 5;             // you can set how many record to be shown per page...
$this1 = $eu + $limit; 
$back = $eu - $limit; 
$next = $eu + $limit; 


$nume = $dbo->query("select count(id) from products")->fetchColumn();

echo "<TABLE>";
echo  "<tr><th>ID</th><th>SKU</th><th>Price</th></tr>";

$query=" SELECT * FROM products  limit $eu, $limit ";

foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) {
$i=$i+1;   

echo "<tr><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[sku]</td><td>$row[price]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

if($nume > $limit ){

echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='30%'>";


if($back >=0) { 
    echo "<a href='$page_name?start=$back'>PREV</a>"; 
} 

echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";
$i=0;
$l=1;
for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit){
    if($i <> $eu){
        echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i'>$l</a> ";
    }
    else { 
        echo "$l";
    }
    $l=$l+1;
}


echo "</td><td  align='right' width='30%'>";

if($this1 < $nume) { 
echo "<a href='$page_name?start=$next'>NEXT</a>";} 
echo "</td></tr></table>";

} 
?>

</body>

</html>
```

I am using PDO,

```
<?Php
$dbhost_name = "localhost";
$database = "stackoverflow";// database name
$username = "root"; // user name
$password = ""; // password 

try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>
```

Please let me know if your problem doesn't solve yet.

Comment: Hi Awatl! I have a couple of issues with this code above. The first is that I'm getting a Notice. Notice: Undefined index:start in C:\Apache24\htdocs\pagination-example.php on line 15. And the second question I had was I wanted the url to show page=1 or page = 2 etc... Not start = 0, start = 5 or start= 10.

Comment: Hello, Mark that is good news that my code is useful for you.

Comment: first, let me tell you what is "Undefined index" when the page is GET some value from the file, I.E product.php?id=2 when someone removes id=2 then PHP will generate this Notice, it can easily be fixed simply by adding its parameters in our example id=2

Comment: For your second question
for example, you want to start showing your product from 5 instead of 0 WHEN user doesn't put parameter "start" or you decided to show from 5 which is skipping 1 page = 5 items,
if($start == "" || $start < 0){
 header('location: index2.php?start=5');
}

if you add this simple code after you will get the value of the start variable, like this,
...
$page_name="index2.php"; //  If you use this code with a different page ( or file ) name then change this 
$start=$_GET['start'];

if($start == "" || $start < 0){
 header('location: index2.php?start=5');
}

Comment: I am apologizing, I don't know why but it doesn't let me edit my answer, please let me know if you still have the problem.

Comment: What parameters am I putting where for the first issue with the Undefined index?

Comment: OK! I resolved the first issue with Undefined index and the second issue was getting the page=1, page=2, page=3, etc... to work properly. The code above works on the landing page but I need to make some changes to the calculations for the page numbers. Any suggestions? My problem is with the $i = $i + $limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181421/discussion-between-awatitwork-and-mark).

Answer (score 1):

On line 25 you have

```
printf("<a href='%s'>Previous</a>", url);
```

You have defined $url but you missed the $ when you referenced it.

You should have:

```
printf("<a href='%s'>Previous</a>", $url);
```

You have also made the same mistake in the next `if` statement.

Comment: OK! I just revised my code and now it doesn't show the query in a table. I just see the Next Page link. I probably need to create a table right?

Comment: Yea, probably something to do with your html.